# How to upgrade pip version from 10.0.1 to 18.0 in anaconda?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, upgrade

I'm using `Anaconda`. I want to update `pip` from version `10.0.1` to `18.0` but I can't.

I tried using the code `conda update pip` in Anaconda Prompt but the version has not been changed and It is still `10.0.1`.

The reason I want to update Pip version is to install `cx_freeze`.

Answer (score 2):

First list your conda environment:

```
conda-env list
base        /home/user/anaconda2/
```

Activate your conda environment:

```
source activate /home/user/anaconda2
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 1):

If conda does not work you can always do things from pip (in this case use pip to update pip). Try with:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Make sure you are calling the conda pip and not the pip of the system

Comment: The last sentence might be cryptic for new Python or Anaconda users.

Comment: If I do this, `conda list` shows two versions of pip. v10.0 installed by conda and v18.0 by pip...